# WCF RESTful service not accepting JSON input

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, fiddler

In my case, i have a web service as below,

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "services/CreatePerson", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    string CreatePerson(string data);
```

Its expecting a JSON input. while i am testing this service with Fiddler by passing a JSON string as Request body as below,

```
"{"personName":"Joe", "source":"I", "address":"KK Road"}"
```

and Request Header as

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 54
```

Its not hitting the service method break point while debugging.

At the same time its working for the following JSON as below(replacing double quotes with single quote the previous json),

```
"{'personName':'102',  'source':'I',  'address':'KK Road'}"
```

The service method not taking the JSON string input, as it works well if i pass input as "test"..

Where is the actual problem, please help me to find out....

Comment: So what is the problem after you change the double quotes to single quotes ? Also you can map the json object directly to your method parameters if you pass in an object like this : { "data" : "somevalue"}

Comment: "{'personName':'102',  'source':'I',  'address':'KK Road'}" input is working, but its quite overheard to manage this input at consumer and service side, because the service consumed by android and iphone app should rewrite the code by replacing the double quotes to single quote( as the getting json string using double quotes while serializing their class to json) and on the service i need to replace it to double quotes to deserialize to the corresponding class..

Comment: Ok. So is there a specific reason why you need to pass the data in a single parameter ? I mean for the example above you can create the service method with 3 parameters. And then from the iphone or android client you can create a regular object, serialize it to JSON and pass it to the service. As long as the object has same parameter names, WCF will map it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use the initial and trailing quotes!

Try:

```
{'personName':'102',  'source':'I',  'address':'KK Road'}
```

Also you method should not take a string argument but a class that conforms to the json.

```
 public class M
 {
     public string personName { get; set; }
     public string source { get; set; }
     public string address { get; set; }
 }

 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "services/CreatePerson", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
 string CreatePerson(M data);
```

Comment: Thanks Rechard, i have tried with that too, but it still not hitting the service method. It will hit the service method if i pass the json input as {"M":{  "personId":"102", "source":"I", "allergen":"dust"}},         but at the service all the properties of the class M is null(personId,source,address are null)

Comment: I assume you are doing POST from Fiddler.  What does Fiddler report as the response?

Comment: Yes.I am using entity framework.Its already generated a class named 'Person' by entity which have all the properties that we defined in json input.When i changes the type of the service method to 'Person' and passing the json input as {  "personName":"Joe", "source":"I", "address":"KK Road","createdDate":"12/12/2012"} its giving null in the corresponding properties at service method while debugging. now i have created a separate class named 'PersonData' along with same properties generated by entity framework before, its working perfectly...

Comment: cant we use entity frame work class for the particular table directly in the service method? do we need to create another class with the same properties to handle input ?

Comment: You can use the entity framework classes but they are too heavy to be serialized. So I would suggest to create separate lightweight class for services.